# Get previous values dynamically based on number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a subset of my table:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 02/02/2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 03/01/2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 04/02/2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 01/04/2022 | 5 |
| 2 | 02/04/2022 | 3 |
| 2 | 03/04/2022 | 0 |
| 2 | 04/04/2022 | 10 |

I want to fill the value column where the value is 0 with the last non 0 value for the particular id. I have tried the LAG(1) function but the logic doesn't work where there are more than one 0 value for an id (e.g., in id 1)

Any help will be appreciated.

Transformed table to look like

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 02/02/2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 03/01/2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 04/02/2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 01/04/2022 | 5 |
| 2 | 02/04/2022 | 3 |
| 2 | 03/04/2022 | 3 |
| 2 | 04/04/2022 | 10 |

My attempt below to show my logic, LAG only look at the last value but my table many have more than 1 recurring value for id where value=0, hence LAG 1 doesn't work.
SELECT *, LAG(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY VALUE, DATE ASC) FROM TABLE
ORDER BY VALUE, DATE ASC

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Please edit your question to include code you tried and results you got with it on subset you chose.

Comment: @Aarlaneth i'm not sure where to start. please help and provide the code. thanks

Comment: You said you tried with `LAG` function, show us that attempt (both code you tried and results you got). Problem is that SO is not a code writing service, we want to see your good faith attempt before diverting our time to helping you. In my case, I am not going to go and write everything from scratch. Post your attempt so I can take it and modify it so it works.

Comment: You can read through [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @Aarlaneth thank you--i have gone and edited my post to include my attempt. please help me thanks

Comment: `select id, date, case when value = 0 then max(nullif(value,0)) over(partition by id, grp) else value end as value
from (select *, sum(case when value=0 then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by id order by date rows unbounded preceding) as grp
from tableX) as t
order by id, date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution that works for given sample. It is not most elegant but it works.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    IIF(
     value != 0, 
     value, 
     (SELECT top 1 value 
     FROM table ref 
     WHERE date < orig.date AND id = orig.id AND value != 0 
     ORDER BY date DESC)) 
FROM 
    table orig
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WVMJJIVi)

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to implement this into my db: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Considering you tagged sql-server and this isn't sql server error..

Comment: It is GCP. Sorry.